# How to communicate a lightning report chart in a VF page

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-apps

I want to include a **lightning** report chart on a VF page and use message-passing or any other method to pass the parameters from a VF page to filter the data on the report.

E.g. I only want to should the number > 100 and the parameter **100** is passed from the VF page.

Any idea or direction to do that?

[image: inline]

Comment: I am not sure I understand you 100%, but there is a feature in lightning reports that you can filter it through url params: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=reports_filter_url.htm&type=5

Comment: @ItaiShmida thanks for your reply. Is there any way to do with built-in chart in a lightning way? Also, apart from filter it using url params. Is it possible to filter the chart using javascript message passing from another iframe?

Comment: That I do not know